# Arrays and objects [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm new here, I was wondering if anyone could help me with my Java Script homework assignment.
I've tried looking everywhere else, I'm not sure if I'm bad at looking or if I have a unique problem. My array comes out as a string but I need to create a code that allows me to look within the array and check if it is a Toyota. I thought about using a loop but since it comes out as a string I can't figure out how to properly get in there. I'm bad at explaining but hopefully, someone can help. I'm not sure where it's going wrong but please help in any way.

```js
    
        var studentName = "Alicia";
    
        writeToPage("Assignment for: " + studentName);
        writeToPage("");
    
        writeToPage("Program 1: Writing an Array of Car Makes");
        writeToPage("");
    
        writeToPage("Creating Array: ");
    
        var array_name = car_makes;
        var car_makes = ["Toyota", " Honda", " Audi", " BMW", " Mercedes"];
    
        writeToPage("Displaying Array: ");
    
        writeToPage(car_makes);
    
        writeToPage("Program 2");
        writeToPage("");
    
        writeToPage("Create Car Object: ");
    
        var toyotaCamryCar = new Object();
        toyotaCamryCar['make'] = "Toyota";
        toyotaCamryCar['model'] = "Camry";
        toyotaCamryCar['year'] = "2019";
        toyotaCamryCar['price'] = 25000;
    
        writeToPage("Write the Car Object and Attributes");
    
        writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['make']);
        writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['model']);
        writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['year']);
        writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['price']);
    
        writeToPage("Program 3");
        writeToPage("");
    
        writeToPage("Create an Array of Objects");
    
        var carTypes = [];
        carTypes.push({
          make: "Toyota",
          model: "Camry",
          year: "2018"
        });
        carTypes.push({
          make: "Toyota",
          model: "Corolla",
          year: "2019"
        });
        carTypes.push({
          make: "Audi",
          model: "A4",
          year: "2017"
        });
        carTypes.push({
          make: "BMW",
          model: "i3",
          year: "2018"
        });
        carTypes.push({
          make: "Honda",
          model: "Accord",
          year: "2016"
        });
    
        writeToPage("Displaying Objects: ");
    
        printCarTypes(carTypes);
    
        writeToPage("Program 4");
        writeToPage("");
    
        writeToPage("Check the objects and print out the Toyota ones, use conditionals");
    
        if (carTypes = {
            make: "Toyota"
          }) {
          printCarTypes(carTypes)
        };
    
    
        writeToPage("Program 5");
        writeToPage("");
    
    
        writeToPage("Create the checkQualifies function");
    
        writeToPage("Run the checkQualifies below for each entry of the array From Program 3");
    
    
        writeToPage("Complete");
    
    
        function printCarTypes(carTypes) {
          for (var i = 0; i < carTypes.length; i++) {
            writeToPage("Car Types [" + i + "]: " + JSON.stringify(carTypes[i]));
          }
          writeToPage("");
        }
    
        function writeToPage(strText) {
          var output = document.getElementById("my_output");
          var currentValue = output.innerHTML;
          output.innerHTML = currentValue + "<br/>" + strText;
        }
```

```html
    
        <html>
    
        <head>
          <title>Assignment Seven : Array, Objects, Functions, Methods</title>
          <meta author="My Name" />
        </head>
    
        <body>
          <h1>Javascript Assignment</h1>
    
          <br/>
    
          <h2>Your Output</h2>
    
          <div id="my_output"></div>
    
        </body>
    
        </html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify, your question is about Java_Script_, not Java. They're different languages; it's confusing, I know.

Comment: `printCarTypes(carTypes.filter(x=>x.make=="Toyota"))`

Comment: also, use `==` or `===` to compare, `=` assigns.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked perfectly. For my if statement, should it simply be if(carTypes) or should it be something like if(carTypes["make"] = "Toyota"). I tried both and they seem to produce the same result however I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: In fact, only use `===` to compare, unless you know why you need `==` (at which point you're familiar enough with JS to understand type coercion. Just use `===`).

Comment: `carTypes` is an array, so you need to index it to test a specific element's make, e.g. `if (carTypes[i].make === "Toyota")`

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  It runs perfectly and smoothly. If I have another question regarding the same code but a different topic should I create a new question or post it here in order to avoid duplicating the code?

Comment: Questions are expected to be concise issues.  If you run into a different issue, it should become a new question.  Otherwise questions become too broad and never ending

Comment: It is similar to my other question except now it has to deal with functions, I basically need to create a function that acts the same as the loop but it will check if the date of the car is greater than or equal to 2018. I have tried function checkQualifies(year){
    year >= 2018
  }; and function checkQualifies(){
    printCarTypes(carTypes.filter(year>="2018"))
  }, similar to the help I received for the other question. It needs to output and state that the object qualifies.

Answer (score 0):

You are in need of some kind of loop that checks all the cars inside the carTypes array.
JavaScript has multiple functions that helps you achieve this.

A preferred function in JavaScript is using the `forEach` operator on arrays.
You can read more about this on W3schools => https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp.

For your problem, I have written your solution down below.
all you needed is

```
  let toyotaCars = [];
  carTypes.forEach(carType => {
    if(carType.make == "Toyota") toyotaCars.push(carType)
  })
  printCarTypes(toyotaCars)
```

I used an arrow function as well read more about this here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Assignment Seven : Array, Objects, Functions, Methods</title>
  <meta author="My Name" />
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Javascript Assignment</h1>

  <br/>

  <h2>Your Output</h2>

  <div id="my_output"></div>


</body>

</html>

<script>
  var studentName = "Alicia";

  writeToPage("Assignment for: " + studentName);
  writeToPage("");

  writeToPage("Program 1: Writing an Array of Car Makes");
  writeToPage("");

  writeToPage("Creating Array: ");

  var array_name = car_makes;
  var car_makes = ["Toyota", " Honda", " Audi", " BMW", " Mercedes"];

  writeToPage("Displaying Array: ");

  writeToPage(car_makes);

  writeToPage("Program 2");
  writeToPage("");

  writeToPage("Create Car Object: ");

  var toyotaCamryCar = new Object();
  toyotaCamryCar['make'] = "Toyota";
  toyotaCamryCar['model'] = "Camry";
  toyotaCamryCar['year'] = "2019";
  toyotaCamryCar['price'] = 25000;

  writeToPage("Write the Car Object and Attributes");

  writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['make']);
  writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['model']);
  writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['year']);
  writeToPage(toyotaCamryCar['price']);

  writeToPage("Program 3");
  writeToPage("");

  writeToPage("Create an Array of Objects");

  var carTypes = [];
  carTypes.push({
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Camry",
    year: "2018"
  });
  carTypes.push({
    make: "Toyota",
    model: "Corolla",
    year: "2019"
  });
  carTypes.push({
    make: "Audi",
    model: "A4",
    year: "2017"
  });
  carTypes.push({
    make: "BMW",
    model: "i3",
    year: "2018"
  });
  carTypes.push({
    make: "Honda",
    model: "Accord",
    year: "2016"
  });

  writeToPage("Displaying Objects: ");

  printCarTypes(carTypes);

  writeToPage("Program 4");
  writeToPage("");

  writeToPage("Check the objects and print out the Toyota ones, use conditionals");

  let toyotaCars = [];
  carTypes.forEach(carType => {
    if(carType.make == "Toyota") toyotaCars.push(carType)
  })
  printCarTypes(toyotaCars)


  if (carTypes = {
      make: "Toyota"
    }) {
    printCarTypes(carTypes)
  };


  writeToPage("Program 5");
  writeToPage("");


  writeToPage("Create the checkQualifies function");

  writeToPage("Run the checkQualifies below for each entry of the array From Program 3");


  writeToPage("Complete");


  function printCarTypes(carTypes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < carTypes.length; i++) {
      writeToPage("Car Types [" + i + "]: " + JSON.stringify(carTypes[i]));
    }
    writeToPage("");
  }

  function writeToPage(strText) {
    var output = document.getElementById("my_output");
    var currentValue = output.innerHTML;
    output.innerHTML = currentValue + "<br/>" + strText;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `map` is for making a new array that contains the result of a function on each element of the original array. If you just want to loop over the array without creating a result array, use `forEach`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this answers your question!

```js
    carTypes.forEach(myFunction); // Use of for-each loop
    

> You need to match the object content and then return the matching
> object. My code snippet is not returning the matching object but it
> does print on object content on the page

    function myFunction(item, index) { 
      if(item.make == "Toyota") // match condition in object
        {
            writeToPage("Make: " + item.make + " Model: "+ item.model + " Year: "+ item.year);
        }
    }
```